# Does CLR occupy a continous block of memory?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

When CLR does garbage collection it also compacts the heap. Now if CLR is not using a continuous block of memory, it cannot get rid of the unused space in between and press to objects together, correct?

But if thats true, then another question arises. If a process run by CLR needs more memory than what can be satisfied by what the CLR has currently occupied, how can CLR ensure the newly occupied memory is continuous to the memory currently reserved by CLR? May be that memory is already in use by a non clr process. And hence maybe the available memory is not continuous to the memory already occupied by the CLR. So that now CLR is working between two discontinuous pieces of memory, in that case how would compaction work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just not how it works.  The CLR allocates virtual memory space in large chunks, called *segments*, the underlying winapi call is VirtualAlloc().  The smallest segment it ever allocates is two megabytes.  It will ask for bigger ones if the program consumes memory rapidly.

The GC compacts only the content of a segment.  There is no need to make the segments themselves contiguous in the address space.  Nor could that ever work, the CLR has to deal with the address space being used by not just GC data but also code and other heaps.  Including allocations made for unmanaged code and data.  A typical managed program has at least 10 different heaps.  One of which is the Large Object Heap, the one the GC uses for large objects that are not compacted because moving them is too expensive.  Only objects less than 85,000 bytes end up in the generational heaps and are compacted.

Compacting is useful to avoid fragmentation and improve the L1 cache usage.  A fragment can't be bigger than 85,000 bytes, the L1 data cache is typically 32,768 bytes.  Both well below the smallest segment size.

Answer (score 1):

"May be that memory is already in use by a non clr process."

The CLR is designed to run on modern computers. These have virtual address spaces, i.e. every process has its own contiguous address space. Memory may be physically interleaved, but not logically.

Still, allocated memory may be fragmented. This isn't a big deal. For starters, there are two heaps (small object/large object) and the small object heap is split into 3 generations. So you don't need a single allocation for that anyway.

Compacting does not preserve order. If there's a hole of 16 bytes, it would be far too expensive to move all objects down by 16 bytes. Instead, a single object can be moved into the hole from anywhere - ideally from a page that is otherwise unused, so that can be recycled.